# ANTLR error : java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: offendingToken

Tags: antlr, grammar

I have written the following grammar file and am getting the following error. I have done many google search and some answer says that there something wrong in the grammar. But the following error message does not indicate the specific place, where is the error message  possibly. Can you please advise, why I am getting the error, described below.

```
grammar ArchSpec;  

options {
  language     = Java;  
}  

@lexer::header {
  package iotsuite.parser; 

}

@parser::header {
package iotsuite.parser;
import iotsuite.compiler.*; 
import iotsuite.semanticmodel.*;  

} 

@members {
  private SymbolTable context;     
} 

archSpec : 
     ('structs' ':' struct_def)*  
     'softwarecomponents' ':' (component_def)+
;   

component_def :
    'computationalService' ':' (cs_def)+   
; 

struct_def: 
    CAPITALIZED_ID 
    (structField_def ';')+       
;

structField_def:  
  lc_id ':' dataType 
; 

cs_def:
  CAPITALIZED_ID
   (csGeneratedInfo_def ';')+ 
    (csConsumeInfo_def ';')* 
    (csRequest_def  ';')*
    (cntrlCommand_def ';')* 
    (partition_def ';')+
   ;


csGeneratedInfo_def:
    'generate' lc_id ':'  CAPITALIZED_ID

;

csConsumeInfo_def:
    'consume' lc_id ('from' 'region-hops' ':' INT ':' CAPITALIZED_ID )?     

;

csRequest_def :
   'request' lc_id    
; 

cntrlCommand_def :
    'command'  name = CAPITALIZED_ID '(' (cntrlParameter_def)? ')' 'to'  'region-hops' ':' INT ':' CAPITALIZED_ID    
;

cntrlParameter_def :
    lc_id  (',' parameter_def )?   
; 

partition_def:  
    csDeploymentConstraint='partition-per' ':' CAPITALIZED_ID     
; 

lc_id: ID  
;

dataType: 
  primitiveType 
;

primitiveType:
  (id='Integer' | id='Boolean' | id='String' |  id = 'double' | id = 'long' | id='boolean' )
;

ID  : 'a'..'z'  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' )*
   ;

INT : '0'..'9'('0'..'9')*  ; 

CAPITALIZED_ID: 'A'..'Z' ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' )*;

WS: ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C')+ {$channel = HIDDEN;};
```

Error Message  I am getting on console is the following.

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: offendingToken
    at org.deved.antlride.runtime.AntlrErrorListener.extractToken(AntlrErrorListener.java:111)
    at org.deved.antlride.runtime.AntlrErrorListener.report(AntlrErrorListener.java:79)
    at org.deved.antlride.runtime.AntlrErrorListener.message(AntlrErrorListener.java:63)
    at org.deved.antlride.runtime.AntlrErrorListener.error(AntlrErrorListener.java:53)
    at org.antlr.tool.ErrorManager.grammarError(ErrorManager.java:742)
    at org.antlr.tool.ErrorManager.grammarError(ErrorManager.java:750)
    at org.antlr.tool.NameSpaceChecker.lookForReferencesToUndefinedSymbols(NameSpaceChecker.java:133)
    at org.antlr.tool.NameSpaceChecker.checkConflicts(NameSpaceChecker.java:72)
    at org.antlr.tool.Grammar.checkNameSpaceAndActions(Grammar.java:804)
    at org.antlr.tool.CompositeGrammar.defineGrammarSymbols(CompositeGrammar.java:374)
    at org.antlr.Tool.process(Tool.java:484)
    at org.deved.antlride.runtime.Tool2.main(Tool2.java:24)
```

An instance of input  I parse is the following:

```
softwarecomponents:
    computationalService:
        RoomAvgTemp 
            generate roomAvgTempMeasurement:TempStruct;
            consume tempMeasurement from region-hops:0:Room;
            partition-per : Room;       
        RoomController 
            consume roomAvgTempMeasurement from region-hops:0:Room;
            command SetTemp(setTemp) to region-hops:0:Room;
            partition-per : Room;
```

Comment: I have 2 questions: does the error also occur when testing the grammar outside the ANTLR-IDE? If so, can you also post the input that triggers this error?

Comment: I may not understand your question correctly. However, let me try to answer your question with my understanding. I have installed ANTLR plug-in in Eclipse. On eclipse console, the above error is indicated.

Comment: Err, you've not answered any of my questions :). Let me rephrase: (1) Did you try testing you grammar without the ANTLR-IDE (ANTLR plugin)? And (2) can you post the input you're trying to parse?

Comment: Thanks Bart for detail question. (1) I have not tried to test my grammar without the ANTLR plugin , (2) for your reference, I have edited my question with an instance of input, which I parse using this grammar.